# How to share application settings between multiple servers

Tags: c#, .net, settings, config

I have 2 webservers and 3 application servers with multiple applications.
I would like to be able to have some kind of a system such that applications from all servers could access common basic settings - db connection string, common file server share, smtp server, and such.

The only suggestion I could find was to place all settings in database, but then I would need to put the connection string in machine.config on each server.
I tried to put file on the domain controller and wrote code to figure controller name but I cannot read the file even after impersonating trusted user.

Answer (score 0):

The way that we do this is through a central application server (we call it a business layer).

The connecting applications only have to be configured with the address of the central server and then they can retrieve all of the settings that they need from it (through remoting, web service, wcf, or whatever your preference is).

**Update**

The only other option that comes to mind is using WS-Discovery to send a multi-cast request to find a WCF service that provides the information.

[Here is a link](http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2009/02/13/using-ws-discovery-in-wcf-4-0.aspx) to a quick start guide.

Comment: I know what the business layer is. Still, according to your suggestion each application should be configured with at least a single setting - the ip or url to the remote server. This is a thing I am trying to avoid. Even putting this url in the machine.config would not help - I have 5 web/application servers + numerous workstations with .net apps. I don't want to configure each and every one of them.

Comment: The bottom line is you *have* to configure each app so they at least know *where* to get the configuration. The benefit is your keeping all your configuration in one place so it's easier to maintain, surely the small configuration on each app is worth it?

Comment: The only other option that springs to mind is a multi-cast UDP request. Fortunately, WCF in .Net 4.0 implements this. I have updated the answer with this info.